# How to filter Google Cloud Instances using google-compute-engine python client?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, filter, google-compute-engine, google-api-python-client

I am using

```
Package                  Version
------------------------ ---------
google-api-core          2.0.1
google-auth              2.0.2
google-cloud-compute     0.5.0
google-compute-engine    2.8.13
```

to retrieve google cloud instances data. I was referring to the [docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/compute/latest/compute_v1/instances.html) to get aggregated list of instances. I wasnt able to filter instances based on tags of the compute VM instances. Is there a particular way to do it using python as there is no particular mention about it in the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/compute/latest/compute_v1/instances.html#google.cloud.compute_v1.services.instances.InstancesClient.aggregated_list). ?

Answer (score 2):

Please include your code.

You should be able to apply a `Filter` to [AggregatedListInstancesRequest](https://googleapis.dev/python/compute/latest/compute_v1/types.html#google.cloud.compute_v1.types.AggregatedListInstancesRequest) and you should be able to specify labels, see [Filtering searches using labels](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources#filter). I'm confident (!?) the API is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list#:%7E:text=page%20of%20results.-,filter,-string) refers to the `filter` query parameter. I didn't manage to get it to work with `tags`. But you can still list all the instances and filter it directly.

In the example below I'm looking for the `gke-nginx-1-cluster-846d7440-node` tag.

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute']
sa_file = 'alon-lavian-0474ca3b9309.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(sa_file, scopes=scopes)
service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

project = 'alon-lavian'
zone = 'us-central1-a'

request = service.instances().list(project=project, zone=zone)
while request is not None:
    response = request.execute()
    for instance in response['items']:
        if 'gke-nginx-1-cluster-846d7440-node' in instance['tags']['items']:
            print(instance)

    request = service.instances().list_next(previous_request=request, previous_response=response)
```